# Can't add a unicode character to js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode

I have a .js.erb file that renders a Ruby partial.  Right now, everything works fine, and the first line is

```
<%# encoding: utf-8 %>
```

Later on when I add the line

```
$("#name").text("Name &#x25BC;");
```

Things still work, but the Unicode comes out as the code, not as the character I wanted.  When I replace the above with

```
$("#name").text("Name " + &#x25BC;);
```

The partial just refuses to render.  My Ruby console even lies by saying

```
  Rendered interface/_tan.erb (5.5ms)
  Rendered interface/tan_complete.js.erb (20.0ms)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using jQuery. Try this instead:

```
$("#name").html("Name &#x25BC;");
```

The `.text()` method sets the `innerText` property. The `.html()` method sets the `innerHTML` property. HTML entities render as plain-text when injected into the `innerText` property.

As for why `$("#name").text("Name " + &#x25BC;);` fails to render, I'm fairly sure that the `&` has a special significance in Ruby syntax (though I'm far from an expert) and that the `#` starts a comment, so the line is likely to be syntactically incorrect, thus causing an error which makes the partial fail to render.